# Which character should not be set as values in XML file

Tags: xml, perl, dom, vbscript

I notice that when I configured the XML file values with "&" character , then XML file not open correctly

I guess this is because XML file values should not have some character as &

And "&" Should not set as value in the XML file

Please advice if there are more characters that should not set in the XML as value?  ( or maybe & character is the only the one ?? )

Example of bad value from XML "&"

```
<FolderPath>\EEA\E1\C & W 100\AWQ</FolderPath>
```

Example of right line from XML

```
 <FolderPath>\EEA\E1\C and W 100\AWQ</FolderPath>
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would refer you to: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp

> Some characters have a special meaning in XML.
>
> If you place a character like "<" inside an XML element, it will generate an error because the parser interprets it as the start of a new element.
>
> There are 5 pre-defined entity references in XML:

```
&lt;    <   less than
&gt;    >   greater than
&amp;   &   ampersand 
&apos;  '   apostrophe
&quot;  "   quotation mark
```

You can verify your XML with:
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp

Comment: very clear instrunctions thx +1

Answer (score 5):

The safe thing to do is to always escape as follows:

```
&  ⇒  &amp;
<  ⇒  &lt;
>  ⇒  &gt;
"  ⇒  &quot;
'  ⇒  &apos;
```

---

Detailed answer:

- `&` is special in element text and attribute values. Use `&amp;` instead.
- `<` is special in element text. Use `&lt;` instead.
- `>` is not special by itself.
- `"` is special in attribute values delimited by `"`. Use `&quot;` instead.
- `'` is special in attribute values delimited by `'`. Use `&apos;` instead<sup>[1]</sup>.
- `]]>` is special in element text. Use `]]&gt;` instead.
- `]]>` is special in `CDATA` sections. Use `]]>]]&gt;<![CDATA[` instead.
- `--` can't be used in comments.
- Only the following characters can be found in XML: 0x0009, 0x000A, 0x00D, 0x0020..0xD7FF, 0xE000..0xFFFD, 0x10000..0x10FFFF. There is no way to include the others.

`&amp;`, `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&quot;` and `&apos;` can always be used in element text and attribute values even when it's not necessary to do so, so the safe thing to do is to always escape `&`, `<`, `>`, `"` and `'`. (Alternatively, always escape all of them except single quotes, and never use single quotes as the delimiter for attribute values.)

---

1. In HTML, you have to use `&#39;` instead. An old version of Internet Explorer accidentally didn't support `&apos;` for XHTML (XML-based HTML) either. As such, some people use `&#39;` for XML too.